# Why do metal surfaces reflect thermal signature?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, infrared-radiation

I recently borrowed a thermal camera from a friend and I tried to observe my palm print over a reflective metallic plate. When I looked at it through the camera, it reflected my thermal signature too. Why this happens and how to measure the heat signature for that material?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the metal is simply reflecting your IR emission.  To avoid that you'll have to make sure that reflected light from hot objects does not enter the camera, or enters at very low intensity.  You can view the metal from an angle, view the metal from a distance (your virtual image will be twice as far from the camera compared to the metal) or use a tripod and get out of the picture altogether.  THere might be a "sweet spot" of some combination of distance and angle that works well.  Any don't be roasting marshmallows nearby. :)

Comment: :) Thanks... I don't exactly understand the phenomenon though. What does it actually reflect? Light or the heat itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, your metal plate acts as a mirror. Seeing your own image in it is not surprising because what we call "IR" are actually photons. These photons have less energy than visible photons (IR means infra red, i.e. "energy below the energy of red photons") so you can't see them with your eyes. They are emitted by any hot object (that explains why we say "thermal camera"), and they behave as any other photon : they can be absorbed, reflected, diffused by materials. In your case they're reflected by the plate just like a mirror reflects visible light.

For the rest of your question, Garyp gave you advices on how to avoid this situation in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing but it was a person's reflection from glass showing up on thermal video footage and researched it, this is what I understood.

All objects emit electromagnetic radiation in the form of photons. Photons can have different wavelengths, very long wavelengths like radio waves (low frequency) to very short wavelengths like x-rays and gamma rays (high frequency). In physics, light refers to electromagnetic radiation of any wavelength. Visible light that humans can see is between 400-700 nm, in between ultraviolet light (shorter wavelength than visible light) and infrared light (longer wavelength than visible light). The kind of electromagnetic radiation emitted from an object depends on its temperature; this radiation is due to the vibration of its molecules and is called thermal radiation. Thermal radiation from objects can be emitted at any wavelength; objects around room temperature emit infrared radiation, objects with hotter temperatures emit higher frequency visible light, and even hotter objects emit ultraviolet light. A surface can be heated by an electromagnetic radiation of any frequency as long as it is able to absorb that radiation. A material can reflect, transmit, absorb and/or emit radiation. I thought that the glass absorbed radiation emitted from your body which changed its temperature, and that's why we can see a person's reflection (probably did occur but too minuscule for the thermal camera to detect or for it to be of relevance). But yeah I understand now that it's just the infrared light being reflected off of the glass and detected by the infrared camera.﻿